# Finding Percent that are Different from Selected Value Within Specific Groupings for Each Column (Spark Dataframe)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, aggregate-functions

Hi all so I have an interesting and difficult problem.

Imagine a Spark dataframe like so:

```
A  B  C  D  E
1  q  2  3  4
1  t  5  3  5
1  r  1  2  5
2  r  3  1  3
2  t  8  1  3
2  q  1  2  3
3  t  1  1  2
3  r  2  1  2
3  r  3  1  1
```

Now I have a quite complex problem.

First I want to group by column A. Then I want to find the argmax for column C where column B is equal to r. Then, I want to groupby again for each B not equal to R. Then, I want to compare all other values in the groupby to the 'maximal' value selected previously, for each subsequent column (D and E), and find the percentage that match and the counts.

Thus, the output will be:

```
A  B  TotalCount  Percent-D-Match  Count-D-Match  Percent-E-Match  Count-E-Match
1  q  1           0                0              0                0
1  t  1           0                0              1                1
2  q  1           0                0              1                1
2  t  1           1                1              1                1
3  t  1           1                1              0                0
```

I imagine this will be a complex udaf but I'm unsure how to even approach this. Thanks.

Comment: why `count-E-match` for `1 t` is 1? the same for all the rest of the rows?

Comment: Because it matches r for 1 (in this case 5=5)

Comment: I have updated my answer :) I hope it is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood from your question, you can use the following logic

first step would be to calculate two temporary `dataframe`s for *maxR* and *maxNotR*

```
val maxR = df.filter($"B" === "r").groupBy("A").agg(max("C").as("maxR"))
val maxNotR = df.filter($"B" =!= "r").groupBy("A").agg(max("C").as("maxNotR"))
```

Next step would be to `join` them with the original `dataframe`

```
val joinedDF = df.join(maxR, Seq("A"), "left").join(maxNotR, Seq("A"), "left")
```

Since you don't need the rows with `r` in column `B`, you can `filter` them and generate the `TotalCount` column

```
val dff = joinedDF.filter($"B" =!= "r").groupBy("A", "B", "D", "E", "maxR", "maxNotR").agg(count("B").as("TotalCount"))
```

Final step would be to calculate the expected output by comparing the columns

```
  dff.select($"A",
      $"B",
      $"TotalCount",
      when($"D" === $"maxR" || $"D" === $"maxNotR", 1).otherwise(0).as("Percent-D-Match"),
      (when($"D" === $"maxR", 1).otherwise(0)+when($"D" === $"maxNotR", 1).otherwise(0)).as("Count-D-Match"),
      when($"E" === $"maxR" || $"E" === $"maxNotR", 1).otherwise(0).as("Percent-E-Match"),
      (when($"E" === $"maxR", 1).otherwise(0)+when($"E" === $"maxNotR", 1).otherwise(0)).as("Count-E-Match")
    )
```

This would lead you to final `dataframe` as

```
    +---+---+----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
|A  |B  |TotalCount|Percent-D-Match|Count-D-Match|Percent-E-Match|Count-E-Match|
+---+---+----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
|1  |q  |1         |0              |0            |0              |0            |
|2  |t  |1         |0              |0            |1              |1            |
|3  |t  |1         |1              |1            |0              |0            |
|2  |q  |1         |0              |0            |1              |1            |
|1  |t  |1         |0              |0            |1              |1            |
+---+---+----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: This will not get the correct percentage values if there are more than 1 observation in a grouping.

Comment: `more than 1 observation`? can you clarify the phrase with appropriate example in the question?

Comment: My guess is that he means the percentages always will be 1 or 0 this way. They would probably be calculated by D/E column counts dividend by the total count.